# Client.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given (Discord)

Tags: discord, discord.py

i don't have any idea why i get this error, can anyone help me please.

**Error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\Users\Username
> \Desktop\Discord\main.py", line 8, in 
> class client(discord.Client(intents=Intents.default())): TypeError: Client.**init**() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were
> given

**CODE:**

```
import discord
from discord import Guild, Intents, ui, app_commands
from datetime import datetime
import config

cfg = config.cfg

class client(discord.Client(intents=Intents.default())):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.synced = False

    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.wait_until_ready()
        if not self.synced:
            await tree.sync(Guild = discord.Object(id=588871675605549104))
            self.synced = True
        print(f"Bot conectat cu succes ca si {self.user}.")

class sugestie_modal(ui.Modal, title="Formular Sugestie"):
    answer = ui.TextInput(label="Esti de acord ca vei fi sanctionat daca sugestia ta este facuta in batjocura?", style=discord.TextStyle.short, placeholder="Da?", default="Da/Nu", required=True, max_length=2)

    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Integration):
        embed = discord.Embed(title=self.title, description=f"**{self.answer.label}**\n{self.answer}", timestamp=datetime.now(), color=discord.colour.blue())
        embed.set_author(name=interaction.user, icon_url=interaction.user.avatar)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)


aclient = client()
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(aclient)

@tree.command(guild=discord.Object(id=588871675605549104), name='modal', description='Formular Sugestie')
async def modal(interaction: discord.Integration):
    await interaction.response.send_modal(sugestie_modal())

aclient.run(cfg['BOT_TOKEN'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> class client(discord.Client(intents=Intents.default())):

This is not how inheritance works. The class' name goes between the brackets, and any arguments should be passed in the `super().__init__()` call.

```py
# (Consider making your class name uppercase...)
class client(discord.Client):  # Only pass the name of the parent class, nothing else
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(intents=intents)  # Pass arguments here
```

Also **do not auto-sync, and especially not in `on_ready`!**

Lastly you can access your tree using `aclient.tree`, there's no need to do `app_commands.CommandTree(aclient)`.